# Aligning elements in HTML5

Tags: css, html, devextreme

I am creating a HTML5-Application with DevExtreme.

Now, I have a dxList (List with Items). The Item should look like:

[image]

The Picture on the Left, the Title, Subtitle, DateTime, Multiline-Text and the Picture on the right should be seperate Items (that I can bound it)
Perhaps someone can help me with give me the basic-code of this HTML-Part?

I have tried several hours to do this - but I have problems with the alignment of the individual parts.

Is there a tool which I can use to create basic-layouts for HTML?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SO isn't for just handing out code it's for debugging problems. But there are loads of HTML templates that are free to download online. Plus you can use photoshop to create a line/matrix template